# why do the readalltext method add carriage return and line feed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have an htm-file, lets call it somehtml.htm, with some HTML that I want to collect by using the `File.ReadAllText()`-method.

somehtml.htm:

```
<div>
<h1>A heading</h1>
<p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
```

When I do this:

string temp = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("somehtml.htm");

...the result is this:

```
<div>\r\n
<h1>A heading</h1>\r\n
<p>A paragraph</p>\r\n
</div>\r\n
```

And this doesn't look good when displayed...

According to the documentation for [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), this method is NOT supposed to add \r\n to the resulting string, even though the file contains carriage return and line feed.

Comment: Look at your file with a text editor that shows you `\r\n`. I believe you will find that they already exist in the file.

Comment: "the result is" - where is this "result"? All you've shown us at the moment is the assignment of the text within the file to a string variable. What you're then showing us is the result of *displaying* that text somewhere. How are you displaying this string? In a control, using Response.Write, something else? Show us *that* piece of code.

Comment: sorry, by result, I meant the string i got in return, the tmp.

Comment: tmp = "<div>\r\n <h1>A heading</h1>\r\n <p>A paragraph</p>\r\n</div>\r\n"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably your file contains these already.

MSDN is correct - `ReadAllText` does not add anything to the file.

Look at your file with a text editor that shows you `\r\n`.